# Apply localization on output format

Tags: android, localization

I am doing localisation for my little app but translating strings is not enough. My code is:

`result.setText(hsDist + " " + interval);`

The output in english will be :-

"Major Third"

The spanish(and others) output should be:

"Tercera Mayor"

So the "spanish" version of the code should be:

`result.setText(interval + " " + hsDist);`

Is there a way to choose each line of code depending on localisation? Any other approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can implement a small localization Manager class, which will create a proper string based on current local
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html
example:

//singleton instance

//class member field

```
....
Locale mLocale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;

String getProperOutPutForSampleString()
{
 switch (mLocale)
 {
  case Locale.ENGLISH:
   return hsDist + " " + interval;
  break:

  //etc etc etc
 }
}
...
```

after that you can just simply use it :

```
result.setText(ManagerLocalizedString.getInstance().getProperOutPutForSampleString();
```